# How to create a dict with two sub list?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am trying to loop through two querysets with keys based on dates in the set. Each date has two types of items: Life events and work. The dict should look like this:

```
Timeline['1980']['event'] = "He was born"
Timeline['1992']['work'] = "Symphony No. 1"
Timeline['1993']['event'] = "He was married"
Timeline['1993']['work'] = "Symphony No. 2"
```

How do I create this dictionary?

I tried the following:

```
    timeline = defaultdict(list)
    for o in opus:
        if o.date_comp_f is not None:
            timeline[o.date]['work'].append(o)
    timeline = dict(timeline)

    for e in event:
        if e.date_end_y is not None:
            timeline[e.date]['event'].append(e)
    timeline = dict(timeline)
```

I keep getting bad Key errors.

Comment: What is `Timeline` and what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```py
timeline = {'1980':{'event':'He was born', 'work':'None'}, '1992':{'event':'None', 'work':'Symphony No. 1'}, '1993':{'event':'He was married', 'work':'Symphony No. 2'}}
```

With results:

```py
>>> timeline['1980']['event']
'He was born'
>>> timeline['1992']['work']
'Symphony No. 1'
>>> timeline['1993']['event']
'He was married'
>>> timeline['1993']['work']
'Symphony No. 2'
```

This is a nested dictionary, the external dictionary are keys of dates with values of another dictionary. Internal dictionary are keys of work or event with values of the final value.

And to add more:

```py
>>> timeline['2019'] = {'event':'Asked stackoverflow question', 'work':'unknown'}
>>> timeline
{'1980': {'event': 'He was born', 'work': 'None'}, '1992': {'event': 'None', 'work': 'Symphony No. 1'}, '1993': {'event': 'He was married', 'work': 'Symphony No. 2'}, '2019': {'event': 'Asked stackoverflow question', 'work': 'unknown'}}
```

When you add a new key, you need to make the value your empty dictionary with placeholders for each future key.

```py
timeline['year'] = {'work':'', 'event':''}
```

or just an empty dictionary, though you may end up with missing keys later

```py
timeline['year'] = {}
```

Comment: How do you create the dict? I keep getting bad key error.

Comment: Copy and paste that exact line and it will create that dictionary.

Comment: I've updated my questions. Can you please take a look at my code?

Comment: What does internal dictionary mean?

Comment: Have updated. Though this is for standard dictionary type, since your original question did include the defaultdict code.

Answer (score 0):

```
t = {}
t['1980'] = {
    'event':'He was born',
    'work':'None'
}
```

Or

```
t = {}
t['1980'] = {}
t['1980']['event'] = 'He was born'
t['1980']['work'] = 'None'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want, but I guess you want to initialize a dictionary where you can make such assignments. You may need something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
# Create empty dict for assignment
Timeline = defaultdict(defaultdict)
# store values
Timeline['1980']['event'] = "He was born"
Timeline['1992']['work'] = "Symphony No. 1"
# Create a regular dict for checking if both are equal
TimelineRegular = {'1980':{'event':"He was born"},'1992':{'work':"Symphony No. 1"}}
# check
print(Timeline==TimelineRegular)
```

Output:

```
>>> True
```